# Powershell: Jenkins build hangs attempting to invoke remote PS script

Tags: powershell, jenkins, powershell-remoting

so I am using the Jenkins powershell plugin to simply copy my built package over to a remote share, unpack it and invoke another powershell script which performs some application specific installation (it sits in the package).

Now what happens is, the build powershell script executes successfully up until I execute the script in the remote share, when it executes that line it just hangs...

my execution policy on the remote machine is unrestricted.

Here is a snippet of what I am doing:

```
#create temporary session with timeout of 2 minutes
$pso = new-pssessionoption -OperationTimeout 120000
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $env:remoteServer -sessionOption $pso
Enter-PSSession $session

#Copy distribution to CD server
Copy-Item $src $deployDir -Recurse -Force 

#Locate install script
$installScript = Get-Item($deployDir + "*-distribution\*\install.ps1")
write-host ("Executing install script at location " + $installScript)

#Execute install script
& $installScript $env:installArgs -Y
```

Please note I am new to writing powershell so apologies if my script is awf :D

Has anyone experienced this kind of behaviour and could point out what I am missing/doing wrong?

thanks,

Comment: Are you executing the above manually at a PowerShell prompt or is that part of a script?  If it is part of a script, then using Enter-PSSession is not what you want to use.  It is for interactive use only.  In a script, you would use `Invoke-Command -session $session`.

Comment: it is part of the script that runs in the jenkins build. Aside from that being bad practise, it doesn't stop my script from working does it?

Answer (score 2):

Using `Enter-PSSession` in a script will cause the script to hang.  Use `Invoke-Command` instead.  BTW if you use the -FilePath parameter it will copy the script from the local PC to the remote PC for you.  However, if that script references other scripts you'll have to copy those.

```
Invoke-Command -session $session -FilePath c:\somepath\install.ps1 -Arg "$env:InstallArgs -Y"
```

If you want to handle the copying yourself then do something like this:

```
Invoke-Command -session $session -Arg $src,$deployDir,$env:installArgs -Scriptblock {
    param($src, $deployDir, $installArgs)
    Copy-Item $src $deployDir -Recurse -Force
    $installScript = GetItem "$deployDir*-distribution\*\install.ps1"
    & $installscript "$installArgs -Y"
```

}

Comment: when using -FilePath where does it copy it to? i.e whats the execution location? Also what I am confused about is when executing another script - what permissions is it running with and is it aware of its new environment, if it has in fact been copied accross.

Comment: AFAICT it passes the contents of the script file across the remoting connection as a string and then executes that string without ever saving it to a file.

Comment: By default, scripts running in a remote session run with admin privileges.

Comment: i think its -ArgumentList is it not? Also, how do I avoid this prompt when it tries to execute the install script?

Comment: Invoke-Command won't cause a prompt so it must be something in your installscript that is prompting or perhaps its the arguments to installscript.  It's kind of hard to know without knowing what installscript is doing and what arguments is getting passed in via $installArgs.